# How to build a photo gallery application using google app engine using GAE and Python

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to develop a photo gallery application using google app engine and python. Can someone please point me to good resources/articles/documentation on this? Thanks.

Comment: This is a very open-ended question. Do you know Python? Do you know GAE? Do you know any web programming (HTML+CSS+JavaScript)?

Comment: I know python. I have run the tutorial of GAE completely. I have worked with web programming using HTML/JS/Perl-CGI as well. Not an expert. But can find my way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone [this](https://github.com/Quasimo/FotoRatan/) github repo and have fun.

Here is the [live demo](http://fotoratan.appspot.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am currently using it and working towards building my application.